# Get control over Bitdefender Antivirus actions

Tags: anti-virus, bitdefender

I really hate that software is trending towards "let me do this for you". I know there are lots of people (especially when it comes to security) who don't know how to handle "threats" but Bitdefender is shooting so many false-alarms which annoys me.

The only way to avoid this behaviour is excluding the directory or executable in Antivirus settings. Is there no option like I was used to have it with others that you simply choose what it should do if it finds any suspicious application? Like "maybe not instantly delete the files".

Else I guess it's once again time to switch to another product.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely know what you mean, recall this from older antivirus software. Curiously enough and just for reference I checked my Avast Free Antivirus to check if this existed as well; couldn't find it.

It appears that you either need to explicity create a bypass path or do manual scannings. So basically automatic scans appear to not have this granularity. Makes sense considering that the average Joe just wants/needs a sort of plug-n-play which does not require any expertise or knowledge to deal with day to day threats. [Bifender user guide here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiG1uv2t9XYAhXtcd8KHdstBFUQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.bitdefender.com%2Fresources%2Fmedia%2Fmaterials%2F2017%2Fuserguides%2Fen_EN%2Fbitdefender_tsmd_2017_userguide_en.pdf&usg=AOvVaw29lzQ9OkOSb1wuscoVfvle).

From the Antivirus Scan Wizard Whenever you initiate an on-demand scan you can decide to take either delete or take no action.
pag 93

An option could be to do a custom scan, this way if you have a directory/folder that will give a false positive will be excluded. 
https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-configure-a-custom-scan-with-bitdefender-1956.html

This is a good option because if you are downloading files, or have a torrent folder, where it is highly likely or even expected to become a false positive, you have more granular control.

The other way is configure exclusions to apply to on-access or on-demand scanning only, or to both. (This you are already aware)
pag 97

Alert intensity pag 132 only talks about going "Paranoid mode" but does not give further modes information.
pag 132

Comment: Sadly only workarounds but not a really satisfying solution. Well after Bitdefender blocked an installer and managed to corrupt Windows so terribly hard so that it wouldn't boot anymore I tried to uninstall it for good. Ended up refreshing my Windows because it couldn't be uninstalled without bricking Windows. Went back to Kaspersky which so far has proved to be far less error-prone (also in case of false-positives).